# How can I determine whether a back button is displayed?

Tags: ios

In an iOS app, how can I determine whether a back button is displayed? Ideally, I'd like to know this in my controller's `loadView` method.

Here's what I've tried in `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, and `viewWillAppear`:

`if (self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem)`

and this:

`if (self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem)`

Neither of those work - they're always nil (the expression evaluates to false), even when there is a back button on the screen. What I'd ultimately like to do is set a Cancel button as the `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, but only if there's no back button. If there is a back button, we don't need the Cancel button. As it is, setting the `leftBarButtonItem` is overriding the back button, so we're seeing a Cancel button all the time - even when there should be a back button.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're asking the wrong object for its `backBarButtonItem`. This property controls how an object is represented when it is the "back" item in the navigation stack.

Therefore, you need to be asking the view controller at the level *below* where you are in the navigation stack what its `backBarButtonItem` is:

```
int n = [self.navigationController.viewControllers count] - 2;
if (n >= 0)
    if ([(UIViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:n]navigationItem].backBarButtonItem == nil)
        // Do your thing....
```

You may need to check if the navigation controller has added your viewController to the stack at the time you are executing this code, the top view controller may still be the previous one. I've checked in `viewWillAppear` and the stack does contain the new top controller at this point.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem);
if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem == NULL) {
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(addLaunch)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
    [cancelButton release];
}
```

this code works, its in the viewDidAppear, if your controller is null, theres no button, so i add the cancel button, its not a back item though, just a regular:] hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`loadView` is too early. The earliest you could check this is in `viewDidLoad`. You may need to wait for `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just tried both of my 'if' statements from the question in viewWillAppear, and I'm getting the same results - they're still always nil and therefore not telling me what I want to know.

Comment: Make sure that `self.navigationItem` isn't `nil`. The latest that this could apply is `viewDidAppear`. If you're not seeing it there, you're not getting the right object.

Comment: Thanks again. I've verified that `self.navigationItem` is not nil. I tested this in `viewDidAppear` and am still getting the same results.

Comment: I had to wait for viewDidAppear

Answer (score 0):

Search for the following

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem
```

instead of `backBarButtonItem`.

If `backItem` exists then you are on navigation stack further than rootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code:

```
if (![[[self.parentViewController childViewControllers] firstObject] isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {

}
```